# Get-BpaModel Powershell cmdlet fails on "Microsoft/Windows/DirectoryServices" with index out of range error

Tags: windows, powershell, domain-controller

Get-BpaModel enumerates through all available bpa models. I run it from one of our dc with domain admin privileges.
It started to fail today on fourth model (it enumerates ADRMS, CertificateServices and DHCPServer) - then immediatelly comes index out of range error (where "Microsoft/Windows/DirectoryServices" should come).
[image: Get-BpaModel - result without parameters]

The same command works on other DCs without problems. What's stranger, this was still working yesterday. I haven't found anything about this error for this cmdlet over internet.
The server was rebooted, but no luck. The same problem occurs now when i try to run Get-BpaResult on this machine for the very same model. Could it be, that the maximum number of reports have been generated and one has to remove them somehow?

Comment: can you share the command and the strings you are using to get the output.  Without that it's pretty difficult to provide any guidance or you just typing get-bpamodel without any parameters?

Comment: Sure, it's nothing fancy. https://imgur.com/HVykZOw It looks like a bug to me, honestly. The very same error occurs whenever i run BPA from Servermanager.

Comment: Error comes also immediately after running: Get-BpaResult "Microsoft/Windows/DirectoryServices"